# How do I make a custom player to be clickable on Facebook feed/profile like Soundcloud?

Tags: facebook, soundcloud

I've notice that when you share a soundcloud link in facebook, and users click play on it,
it won't open a new window, instead it will expand the widget inside facebook feed and reveal a full player allowing the user to listen to the music without leaving facebook. The entire widget is acutally an iframe. 
Kind of like what happens when playing videos, but with a custom player.

How can I do it for my own site that streams music?

Comment: This is something that is done on Facebook side – they have integrations with selected partners.